# How to remove vertical scroll bar space and Arrows (should be invisible)

Tags: html, css, jsp, scroll, scrollbar

I used style="overflow: hidden;white-space:nowrap;"

scroll bar is removed , but the arrows are not getting removed , for a body tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
style="overflow-y: hidden;"
```

You should not really not use inline styles. Try write it like this:

```
<head>
  <style="text/css">
    #container { overflow: hidden; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">Content goes here</div>
</body>
```

Could I see your code if that does not work as I can't see what you have done.

EDIT:

Not sure if I completely get what you are trying to achieve.

Add the following style to the page.

```
  <style="text/css">
    .hideOverflow { overflow: hidden; }
  </style>
```

Are you using jQuery?

If so, add this within your window.open event.

```
 $('body').addClass('hideOverflow');
```

Can I see your window.open script?

Comment: I used window.open and left the scrollable default which is YES.

After the Window Is openedI need to disable the scrolling for the body 

along with disabling of scrolling i need to remove the arrows and space that the scroll bar takes with
the arrows

Comment: <body style="overflow-y: hidden;height: 100vh;">  I am just testing the styles , i will not be writing inline style

Comment: Updated my comment. Can I see your window.open script?

Comment: window.open( url, 'AST', 'top=0, left=0, height=' + (screen.height - 20) + ', width=' + screen.width + ', resizable=no,scrollbars=yes' );

I should not change the window.open anything